# How to add two List<Class> together in c#?

Tags: c#

I have two `List<Student>` that I want to concat.

`Student` is just a class that contains a few properties.

I also have another `Form` that creates the `Student` and populates a `List<Student>`

From there, when the `StudentCreator` closes, I want the `List<Student>` in `StudentCreator` to be concated to the `List<Student>` in the main form. Effectively updating the main list.

This is the main bit of code I'm having trouble with, I get an error saying I can't convert some `IEnumerable<something>` to `List<something>`

```
private void update_students(addStudent s)
        {
            Form activeForm = Form.ActiveForm;
            if(activeForm == this)
            {
                tempList = s.StudentList;
                studentList_HomeForm = tempList.Concat(tempList);
            }
        }
```

This is the main line that gives the error

```
tempList.Concat(tempList)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Call `tempList.Concat(tempList).ToList()` (note that you are concatenating the same list with itself by the way).

Comment: Yep I am aware of that thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

`tempList.Concat` returns an enumerable, something you can iterate over. If you want to transform that into a list, you can call `ToList()`:

```
var newList = tempList.Concat(tempList).ToList();
// you are basically copying the same list... is this intentional?
```

Another approach you could take is creating a new list, iterate over the existing lists and add them to the newly created list:

```
List<Student> newList = new List<Student>(firstList); // start of by copying list 1

// Add every item from list 2, one by one
foreach (Student s in secondList)
{
    newList.Add(s);
}

// Add every item from list 2, at once
newList.AddRange(secondList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AddRange method -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
studentList.AddRange(tempList);
```